# Substitution from 2nd to 4th occurrence using sed Command

Tags: unix, sed

[image]

I want to substitute the p with "@" from 2nd occurrence to 4th occurrence.

```
sed 's/p/@/2g' file.txt
```

This command substitutes from the 2nd occurrence up to the last occurrence of "p".
But 1 want to substitute from 2nd to 4th.
So how to do it ?

Comment: Just repeat the command without `g` three times: `sed -e 's/p/@/2' -e 's/p/@/2' -e 's/p/@/2' file`.

Comment: Ok, this one works, is there any other way

Comment: You should explain your requirements in the question. If a solution works for you, why not use it?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I just want to know is there any other way.

Comment: You should ask that in the question body after explaining why `sed -e 's/p/@/2' -e 's/p/@/2' -e 's/p/@/2'` or `sed -e's/p/@/2'{,,}` is not what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is bash or zsh, you can make use of brace expansion.

```
sed -e's/p/@/2'{,,} file
```

`{,,}` will repeat `-e's/p/@/2'` thrice, so it'll replace 2nd, 3rd and 4th `p`s.

Comment: Thanks this one works, is there any other way using sed command.

Comment: Perhaps `sed -e's/p/@/'{4..2} file`?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/p/\n/5g;s/p/@/2g;y/\n/p/' file
```

Replace the 5th and subsequent `p`'s on a line with newline, replace the 2nd and subsequent `p`'s by `@` and finally restore newlines to `p`'s.

Or, with kudos to oguz ismail:

```
sed -e's/p/@/'{4..2} file
```

This uses bash expansion to generate the substitution strings for occurrences of `p`'s 2 to 4 but in reverse (forward substitution would not take into account previous substitutions).